# Asp.NET Bulleted List Control's Click event raising the issue

Tags: asp.net

Please see the below code.
Home.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Home.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.Home" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:BulletedList ID="BulletedList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1" 
            DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Description" 
            DisplayMode="HyperLink" OnClick="BulletedList1_Click"></asp:BulletedList>
        <asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource1" runat="server">
            <Data>
            <pagelifecycle> 
                <Step Name="Page Request" Description ="The Page Request occurs before page life cycle begins. When Page is requested by the user, ASP.NET determines whether the page needs to be parsed and compiled or whether the cached version of the page can be sent in response without running the page."></Step>
            </pagelifecycle>
                </Data>
        </asp:XmlDataSource>
        <asp:TextBox ID="Description" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="10" Columns ="250" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Home.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class Home : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {  
        }

        protected void BulletedList1_Click(object sender, BulletedListEventArgs e)
        {
           Description.Text = BulletedList1.Items[e.Index].Value.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

And when i run this page, it gives the below error,

HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Why this error comes and what I missed ?

Comment: How is your site hosted - IIS, or VS web server ? When you say "when I run this page", how are you doing this - directly from Visual Studio ?

Comment: VS Web Server. 
And this error comes when I have directly run from Visual studio.

Comment: So you get a 404 when you run (press F5 or the Play button) inside Visual Studio ? Or do you have to click an item in the bulleted list to get the 404 ? Have you specified that home.aspx is your default page ?

Answer (score 0):

Change Display Mode HYPERLINK to LINKBUTTON. It should work.

```
  <asp:BulletedList ID="BulletedList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1"
                DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Description"
                DisplayMode="LinkButton" OnClick="BulletedList1_Click">
            </asp:BulletedList>
            <asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource1" runat="server">
            <Data>
            <pagelifecycle> 
                <Step Name="Page Request" Description ="The Page Request occurs before page life cycle begins. When Page is requested by the user, ASP.NET determines whether the page needs to be parsed and compiled or whether the cached version of the page can be sent in response without running the page."></Step>
            </pagelifecycle>
                </Data>
        </asp:XmlDataSource>
        <asp:TextBox ID="Description" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="10" Columns="250" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```